# index.php in CodeIgniter 4 is showing when i use form_open

Tags: codeigniter-4

i have removed index.php and public folder path from my CodeIgniter 4 project by changing path in index.php of root file but when I used form_open() helper in my view I am getting index.php in  base URL which gives error in calling controller method. so I can remove index.php from  form_open tag ?

am using custom routes not automated created routes

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of writing, you can either use `form_open(base_url('your_relative_path'))`

Or make a copy of `form_open` into your `Common.php` file, where you apply `base_url` to the `$action` automatically.